# How to Declare a Variable for Later in a Component?

Tags: angular, typescript, variable-declaration

I have a component which has variables that don't get assigned till ngAfterViewInit. I want to use those variables outside the init as well, but I don't know how. (Below is what I was thinking, but its gives an error saying Type 'Map' is not assignable to type 'undefined')

```
    export class DummyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      map = null;
      mousePosition = undefined;
  

      ngAfterViewInit(): void {


        this.map = new Map({
         target: 'map',
         layers: [layer],
         view: view
        });
      }

      update(){ this.map.on(...) => {...}}
```

Comment: instead of ```map = null;``` try ```map: Map;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a type safety error. By default a new angular project will create a `tsconfig.json` file with the setting [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) to set to `true`. This, in turn, will control the setting [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) and have it set to `true` which means that if you do not constrain a variable/field instance explicitly it will be constrained to the assigned value's type.

As you assign `map` to `null` the default allowed type is now `null` as you did not define a type when you defined the field. You can solve by specify allowed types for the field `map` to include both `null` and `Map`.

```
map: Map | null = null;
```

Now either assignment will be allowed. Do keep in mind that in your code you must also assert the type for the field when you want to access it if multiple types are allowed. Example:

```
otherMethod(): void {
  if (this.map !== null) {
    this.map. // do something with the map field
  }
}
```